# Entity Framework Core: DbUpdateConcurrencyException on Update with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm currently learning .NET Core with ASP.NET Identity and Entity Framework Core, and I've encountered an issue on a default application when trying to update information about a game entity.

Here's a summary of my setup - custom entities:

```
// Game.cs - Represents the main game entity
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string CreatorId { get; set; } = null!;
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? WinnerId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser? Winner { get; set; } = null!;
    public int RemainingPlayers { get; set; }
    public int EliminatedPlayers { get; set; }
}

public class FixtureSet
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Fixture
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FixtureSetId { get; set; }
    public FixtureSet FixtureSet { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public string? AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public FixtureOutcome FixtureOutcome { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FixtureSet> FixtureSets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fixture> Fixtures { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
                    .HasOne(g => g.Creator) 
                    .WithMany() 
                    .HasForeignKey(g => g.CreatorId) 
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
                    .HasOne(g => g.Winner) 
                    .WithMany() 
                    .HasForeignKey(g => g.WinnerId) 
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 

        //seed data...
    }
}
```

Update controller methods:

```
public IActionResult Update(int gameId)
{
    Game? game = _dbContext.Games
        .Include(x => x.Winner)
        .Include(x => x.Creator)
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == gameId);

    if (game == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }

    return View(game);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update(Game game)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _dbContext.Games.Update(game);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(game);
}
```

`Update.cshtml`:

```
@model LastPersonStanding.Domain.Entities.Game

<div class="w-100 card border-0 p-4">
    <div class="card-header bg-success bg-gradient ml-0 py-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="text-white py-2">Update Game</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body border p-4">
        <form method="post" class="row" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="p-3">
                <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
                    <label asp-for="Id" class="ms-2">Game Id</label>
                    <p class="form-control border shadow">@Model.Id</p>
                </div>
                @*<div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.Creator.Id" class="ms-2">Creator Id</label>
                    <p class="form-control border shadow">@Model.CreatorId</p>
                </div>*@
                <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
                    <input asp-for="Creator.FirstName" class="form-control border shadow" />
                    <label asp-for="Creator.FirstName" class="ms-2">First Name</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Creator.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
                    <input asp-for="Creator.LastName" class="form-control border shadow" />
                    <label asp-for="Creator.LastName" class="ms-2">Last Name</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Creator.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control border shadow" />
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="ms-2"></label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-2">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100">
                            <i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i> Update
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                        <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">
                            <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i> Cancel
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
            <input asp-for="CreatorId" hidden />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

**The issue**

When hitting the `[HttpPost]` update method with a valid model, I get the following error:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

**Additional Context**

- The seed data works correctly and all my dbsets (with seed data) exist in my SQL database
- The Creator and Winner relationships are configured in the OnModelCreating method using `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.
- I am linking my game table to the `[AspNetUsers]` table in order to know the user who creates a game and the user who wins the game (there are 2 navigation properties on the game entity to `AspNetUsers`)
- I've extended the identity user class with a class called application user
- The error is thrown on the `_dbContext.SaveChanges();` line of code in the update method
- I am following a course on Udemy which uses different entities and relationships but the code in the controller is the same. There is no error on the course

I've tried reviewing the documentation on concurrency exceptions but haven't been able to resolve the issue. I've also searched on this forum and attempted to implement some of the solutions. It has to be down to my limited understanding of these topics.

Any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` would be greatly appreciated. This is fairly new so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

**Edit1**: While this code is not intended for production use, its purpose is to establish a connection between code and a SQL database using Entity Framework Core. The primary goal is to facilitate learning about migrations and related concepts.

**Edit2:** I've eliminated the two foreign key 'ApplicationUser' properties, 'Winner' and 'Creator', from the `Game` entity. As a result, I can now successfully execute the Update POST controller action and observe the data accurately reflected in the games table. However, this issue raises concerns about the relationship with the ASPNETUSERS table in ASP.NET Identity. My initial intention was to establish a reference to the ID of the user responsible for creating and winning the game. Is this not a feasible approach?

Thank you

Comment: `public IActionResult Update(Game game)` <-- This is a great way to get your database hacked...

Comment: Show us your HTML View for `GET Update(gameId)`, including your full `<form>` element.

Comment: @Dai This will never be production code and if you would like to explain why it's a good way to get hacked that would be much more useful!

Comment: ...because anyone can set any HTML `<input>` to overwrite arbitrary members of `Game`, including PKs and FKs.

Comment: okay @Dai, thanks for that, anything re: the actual error please?

Comment: There are so many questions on this issue in combination with ASP.Net. Please look again for these questions. It's extremely likely that you're facing the common cause, a lacking Id value coming from the frontend.

Comment: There's too many things to follow-up here - at the very least I'll say you should add `[FromForm]` to your `Game` parameter in your POST method. What does your EF `Entry<Game>` object look like right-after you pass it to `.Update()`?

Comment: Id = 1
Name = "Sample Game 123"
CreatorId = "20f45987-5507-4563-a5f7-9d21d574e50e"
ApplicationUser Creator = ASP.NET User Object (matching the CretaorId)
CreatedDate = {01/01/0001 00:00:00}
WinnerId = null
Winner = null
RemainingPlayers = 0
EliminatedPlayers = 0

Also, to your concern about getting hacked, the plan would be to only open the update action to admin users. I was planning on looking into using the [Authorize] attribute shipped with Identity. I have not made it that far yet tho due to this issue!

Comment: I've eliminated the two foreign key 'ApplicationUser' navigation properties, Winner and Creator, from the Game entity's ApplicationUser. As a result, I can now successfully execute the Update POST controller action and observe the data accurately reflected in the games table. However, this issue raises concerns about the relationship with the ASPNETUSERS table in ASP.NET Identity. My initial intention was to establish a reference to the ID of the user responsible for creating and winning the game. Is this not a feasible approach?